# How to manually trigger a net.socket error event during testing

Tags: node.js, sockets, mocha.js

I wrote a TCP server using Node.js and on my tests (with Mocha) I'm testing that the server actually emits all the events it should. The one problem that I'm finding is that I cannot trigger the [error](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error_1) event at will so I cannot automate this test.

```
    socket.on('error', function()
    {
        // How do I test this?
    });
```

Is there a way to trigger this event manually? O maybe craft a corrupt packet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can emit it manually: `socket.emit('error', new Error('foo bar baz'));`

Comment: Is this the way you'd go for unit testing or would you rather do it differently?

Comment: Yes, it's the simplest and most direct route.